# How to tell program to sleep for 60 seconds after 50 actions have been completed (emails sent) in python

Tags: python, excel, email, gmail

I have this code that sends out emails individually through gmail from a list of emails in an excel file. I just want to know how to make the bot pause for 60 seconds after it's sent 50 emails and then continue with the list after the 60 seconds is up. I'm just trying to be safe with gmails daily limits.

```
import smtplib
import openpyxl as xl
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
username = str(input('Your Username:' ))
password = str(input('Your Password:' ))
From = username
Subject = 'Free Beats and Samples For You :)'
wb = xl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\19548\Documents\EMAILS.xlsx')
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('EMAIL TEST - Sheet1')
names = []
emails = []
for cell in sheet1['A']:
    emails.append(cell.value)
for cell in sheet1['B']:
    names.append(cell.value)
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
for i in range(len(emails)):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = username
    msg['To'] = emails[i]
    msg['Subject'] = Subject
    text = '''
{}
'''.format(names[i])
    msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
    message = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(username, emails[i], message)
    print('Mail sent to', emails[i])
server.quit()
print('All emails sent successfully!')
```

Comment: Count the numbers of mails send, as soon as they are 50 sent, time.sleep()

Answer (score 0):

You can use `time.sleep()` to wait a given number of seconds, and you can keep track of the number of emails sent using a variable that gets incremented with each iteration of the loop. Since you're already working with both the emails themselves and their indices, you can simplify this counting by using Python's `enumerate` function, which gives you both the next value and its corresponding index:

```
for index, email in enumerate(emails, start=1):
    msg = <...>
    message = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(username, email, message)
    if index % 50 == 0:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(your_value%50==0):
    time.sleep(60)
```